# How do you store them in matrices from 5-fold cross-validation that can be used in subsequent calculations?

Tags: python

I try to use the following code to do 5-fold cross-validation for dataset X of size 351 by 14. I want to split X into 80% for the training of size 281 by 14 and resting matrix `70 by 14` for testing.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedKFold
kf = KFold(n_splits=5,  random_state=None)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
```

Then I have five groups of training dataset and testing dataset. How do you store them in matrices that can be used in subsequent calculations? Like `X_tr1` of size 281 by 14 and `X_te1` of size 70 by 14. `X_tr2`, ..., `X_tr5'.

For example, I want to use `X_tr3` in K means:
 `kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0).fit(X_tr3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
split_arr = list(kf.split(X))
# `split_arr` is now an array of (train, test) tuples
print(split_arr[0][0]) # 'X_tr1' in your example
print(split_arr[0][1]) # 'X_te1' in your example
```

Comment: But how to reshape `split_arr[0][0]` to a 280 by 14 matrix but not a `[280, ]` array?

Comment: If I use this one in `kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(dfX_train)`. There is an error: ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=.....

Comment: Also, the result of your `split_arr[0][0]` seems different from my original `X`? I am not sure why....