# How to write code for a 5-fold Cross Validation?

Tags: python

I have code for splitting a data set `dfXa` of size 351 by 14 into 10 fold and choosing one fold for validation denoted by  `dfX_val` of size 35 by 14 and resting 9 fold for training by `dfX_train` of size 316 by 14.

But how to do this for a 5-fold CV? I want to implement 5-fold CV without using the sklearn.

Comment: Why code when you can just use the sklearn library?

Comment: @spectre It's his choice.

Comment: @spectre Because I need to use `dfX_val ` and `dfX_train ` for the computation in the model complement by myself.

Comment: @spectre If I use sklearn library, I face this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69747636/how-do-you-store-them-in-matrices-from-5-fold-cross-validation-that-can-be-used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cross_val_score from the scikit learn library as mentioned [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html).

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
estimator = KMeans(n_clusters=m, random_state=0)
scores = cross_val_score(estimator, X_train, y_train, scoring='accuracy', cv=5)
```

To get the labels, i.e., y_train values you can do:

```
X = df.loc[:, 2:].values
y = df.loc[:, 1].values
```

where df is your dataframe of size 351 by 14. I am assuming here the first comlumn of your data frame are labels, which normally is in such tasks.

Comment: How about the estimator is one model that implemented by myself? I define a function that something like `def(X_train, y_train)` and return the `error` the training error and testing error`. So if I use sklearn, I do not how to use all 5-fold X_train and y_train in my own model.

Comment: The estimator can be a user defined function too. So if you have defined a function for estimator, then you can use it by providing the required parameters.

Comment: But my function returns the error of training and testing. It seems different the result in `estimator = Kmeans('your model parameters here')`?

Comment: your parameters in Kmeans shoud be defined by how many clusters you want. Please check the code again, i have edited its part. Choose the value of m, according to your requirement.

Comment: No... I want to implement a 5-fold CV without using the sklearn. Can you use my code?